# How to use a binary search tree to store strings?

Tags: c, string, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I had previously written C code to insert and traverse integer values in a binary search tree. I tried to make it work for strings as well. I made a few changes like converting all integers to strings and I've also added functions like strcpy() and strcmp() to handle string operations.
But the code doesn't seem to work. Can someone explain to me what went wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct node  
{
    char *str;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};
struct node *root=NULL;

void preorder(struct node *temp)
{
    if(temp==NULL)
        return;
    printf("%s ", temp->str);
    preorder(temp->left);
    preorder(temp->right);

}

void inorder(struct node *temp)
{
    if(temp==NULL)
        return;
    inorder(temp->left);
    printf("%s ", temp->str);
    inorder(temp->right);

}
void postorder(struct node *temp)
{
    if(temp==NULL)
        return;
    postorder(temp->left);
    postorder(temp->right);
    printf("%s ", temp->str);
}

struct node* create(char *str)   // Function to create new node
{
    struct node *new1;
    new1=(struct node*)malloc(strlen(str)+10);
    strcpy(new1->str,str);
    new1->left=NULL;
    new1->right=NULL;
    return new1;
}

struct node* insert(struct node *root,char *str) // Function to insert a node
{
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        root=create(str);
    }
    else if(strcmp(str,root->str)<0)
    {
        root->left = insert(root->left,str);
    }
    else if(strcmp(str,root->str)>0)
    {
       root->right =  insert(root->right,str);
    }
    return root;
}

int main()
{
    char *str;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter value to insert: ");
        scanf("%s",str);
        if(strcmp(str,"-1")==0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            root=insert(root,str);
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe values of the BST traversed in PREORDER are: ");
    preorder(root);
    printf("\nThe values of the BST traversed in INORDER are: ");
    inorder(root);
    printf("\nThe values of the BST traversed in POSTORDER are: ");
    postorder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

If anyone can fix this for me, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what goes wrong? Or give an example of the strings you used and what happened? Also, `new1=(struct node*)malloc(strlen(str)+10);` Why 10? Why not a new node?

Comment: @doctorlove The program compiles without any errors but if I give any input, for instance - "school", The program stops execution and returns nothing.

Comment: `char *` is a **pointer** that points to a char that's stored **somewhere else**. So `new1=(struct node*)malloc(strlen(str)+10);` only allocates memory for the string pointer, not the actual string. You need a separate malloc for the string. Also, don't hard-code sizes, use `sizeof`.

Comment: @Dukeling Thank you for pointing it out. Can you please provide me with the appropriate code to allocate memory for both the string and the struct.

Comment: See: [Allocating memory for a struct when it includes a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263717/allocating-memory-for-a-struct-when-it-includes-a-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Main problem: in `create` you have

```
new1=(struct node*)malloc(strlen(str)+10);
strcpy(new1->str,str);
```

You want a new node

```
new1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

And space for the string

```
new1->str=malloc(strlen(str)+1); //plus 1 for null terminator
```

Then you can do this:

```
strcpy(new1->str,str);
```

Comment: `new1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(node));` should rather be `new1 = malloc(sizeof(node));`, the cast is not necessary. +1 anyway

Comment: Even better - `new1 = malloc( sizeof *new1 );`.

Comment: @doctorlove I've added these lines to my code for memory allocation:

    `new1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`
    `new1->str=malloc(strlen(str)+1);`
    `strcpy(new1->str,str);`

I'm still facing the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I've managed to fix the issue by using a character array instead of a pointer to char in main(). Can anyone explain to me why this happened.

Comment: You still haven't said what went wrong, but the `str` member gets copied straight into in your version with `strcpy(new1->str,str);` but you didn't alloc enough space for the string. The +10 in your malloc buys you a bit of space, but possibly not enough